# How do I get rid of "Nested comment." error thrown by JSLint?

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-statements, jslint

In the following example:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="./js/lib/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

JSLint throws an error on the last line, saying "Nested comment.". I can't seem to find a way to "fix" this on the Internet. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to me to be a bug (or maybe a bit of an oversight) in JSLint. The code that handles HTML comments is as follows:

```js
// ...
case '<!--':
    length = line;
    for (;;) {
        i = source_row.indexOf('--');
        if (i >= 0) {
            break;
        }
        i = source_row.indexOf('<!'); // This line causes the problem
        if (i >= 0) {
            stop_at('nested_comment', line, character + i);
        }
        if (!next_line()) {
            stop_at('unclosed_comment', length, c);
        }
    }
    // ...
```

Basically, when JSLint encounters an opening comment token (`<!--`), it iterates over lines of the source until it comes across a closing comment token (`-->`, not shown in above snippet). If during that iteration it encounters the string `<!` anywhere on any line of the comment, it will raise the "nested comment" error that you are seeing.

Unfortunately, there isn't really a way to work around this, short of not using JSLint for markup validation (which I would usually recommend anyway). I'll have a look to see if I can find a nice way to fix it and then submit a patch.